# Setting boolean value with Vue Firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I’m new to Firebase and am looking to learn more about using Firestore with Vue.js. To implement something very simple to begin with, I have a collection ‘Presenter’ and a doc within called ‘controls’ containing the single value ‘present’ set to `false` as seen here.

[image: Firestore Screenshot]

Phase one of my learning experiment is to simply change this to `true`. Below is what I have so far but I’m getting the error: `“TypeError: Cannot read property ‘presenter’ of undefined”`. Any ideas where I’m going wrong?

```
var config = { ... }

// Initialize Firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = firebase.firestore().collection("presenter");

new Vue({
  el: '#App',
  firebase: {
    presenter: db
  },
  methods: {
    getPresenter() {
      this.$firestore.presenter.doc("controls").set({
        present: true
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getPresenter()
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/writing-data.html#updates-to-collection-and-documents), you need to use `$firestoreRefs.presenter` to refer to the bound `presenter` reference. Also you need to use a `firestore` option, not a `firebase` option one, which is for the Realtime Database.

So the following should do the trick:

```
// Initialize Firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var db = firebase.firestore();

new Vue({
  el: '#App',
  firestore: {
    presenter: db.collection("presenter")
  },
  methods: {
    getPresenter() {
      this.$firestoreRefs.presenter.doc("controls").set({
        present: true
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getPresenter()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Renaud! I didn't even notice I'd included the firebase option. I forget to mention that I am using vue-firestore too. This lead me to the solution which I'm going to post now and mark as the answer.

Comment: Do you know what I'm best Googling to run a function every time a piece of data changes in the Firestore database. You see, I'm trying to control the presentation of a website to a number of my team from my browser, scrolling to the next section in realitime for everyone, on spacebar keyup my side. So ideally, I'm wanting to have a number property which increments everytime I (as the presenter) hits spacebar. I'm I best using the combination of set() to increment and a watcher to push the changes to all who're viewing the site realtime?

Comment: « I'm I best using the combination of set() to increment and a watcher to push the changes to all who're viewing the site realtime?» -> from what I understand yes. If you need more details, please ask a new question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've been playing around with a number of Firebase & Firestore packages as a solution and as Renaud rightly pointed out, the wrong combination of options was my issue.

Here's the combination which worked for me, including the correct script sources which also seemed to be part of the issue.

```
<!-- Vue development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Firebase -->   
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- Firestore -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<!-- vue-firestore -->   
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-firestore"></script>

<script>
var config = { ... }

// Initialize Firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebase.firestore();

new Vue({
  el: '#App',
  firestore() {
    return {
      presenter: db.collection("presenter")
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPresenter() {
      this.$firestore.presenter.doc("controls").set({
        present: true
      })
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.getPresenter()
  }
});
</script>
```